# What is one word for "to take one's side"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the context of protecting someone.

> I saw my brother breaking the glass, but my mother was taking his side.

The word I already searched for and decided to not go with is: supporting, siding, protecting

Answer (score 1):

A few hour of struggling I found that the word I was looking for was [`defending`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defend).

Answer (score 0):

"Favour"
Is the one word for "to take one's side"
For e.g. Rahul took favour of his sister in front of whole class.